# Is it possible to write userDefaults in root preferences using UserDefaults?

Tags: swift, macos, nsuserdefaults

I have command line application thats writes/reads userDefaults. I turned this CLApp in to a bidirectional Xpc such that a client(non root user) or a demon can connect to this service to read and write  default .this can be considered as a centralised data store for settings. 
Then I created a plist file for this xpc service  and then placed it in /Library/LaunchAgents/. 
Launced this service using sudo launchctl load command and everthing worked fine till now.(checked in Activity Monitor and yes! the service is running as root)

When I tried to check for the plist file created by this service ,it is located in  ~/Library/preferences instead of /Library/preferences .Is this the normal behaviour of UserDefaults , If yes then how can I write defaults in root preferences, 
I want my userDefaults accessible to all the users in a particular system for this sake I am implementing a bidirectional XPC hoping it acts a central data store.

New to Mac Development any pointers towards writing defaults in root context is appreciated.
Details :
App is not sandboxed 
Mac os 10.15
Xcode 12.2

I did a little bit search for it and found CFPref.. API can write in root context. It's a low level API and info regarding is very old and a bit hard to understand.I am hoping there may be  work after all this time 
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to create a new user to use when running the xpc instead of using root.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I want all the users+demon in background to access the same plist .I guess I cant share a plist with all users unless its in root directory.

Comment: But you are not sharing the plist file, are you? Isn't it the the content of the plist you are sharing?

Comment: Yeah just the content of plist file, If a particular user changed something ,i want this things to reflect for all others.Can UserDefaults write in root preferences..?

Comment: Isn't it your application that will distribute the changed values to the other connected clients? If so why does it matter where the user defaults file is stored and what user your app is using? Besides, it is generally a bad idea to use the root account.

Comment: When  I said root,I mean my xpc service is running as root process,Its my xpc service that notifies other all clients about key changes and I implemented using userdefaults -kvo ,when ever there is a change it notifies all the clients connected to that service.If i write in user context every user will have their own plist in ~/Library/preferences .this defeats my purpose of having a central setting store.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231954/discussion-between-krishna-vamsi-and-joakim-danielson).